# Complex logarithm properties

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this true or false question about the properties of complex logarithms.

$k $ is any integer and $z $ is any complex number.
$\log_{2k} (iz) = \log_k (i) + \log_k (z)$
$\log_{k} (i^2) = \log_k (i) + \log_k (i)$
$\log_{0} (2i) = \log_0 (i) + \log_0 (i)$
$\log_{0} (i+z) = \log_k (i) + \log_{-k} (z)$

Do complex logarithms have properties like the real logarithms?

In general for complex numbers $\log_{k} (z_1z_2) \neq \log_k (z_1) + \log_k (z_2)$,  so as far as i know they are all false.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to understand how the complex logarithm is defined in terms of the principle branch cut. Because of this things aren't as simple as saying log(zw) = log(z) + log(w).

Comment: What do you mean by $\log_k$?  My guess is that it is a particular branch of the logarithm, but conventions differ, so how exactly are you defining it?

Comment: You shouldn't have any trouble finding counterexamples for some of these, Luis.

Comment: $k $ is the branch of the logarithm.